# XML deserialization into C# object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to convert the Xml data into a C# object.

My C# class is something like this:

```
Public Class XmlModel {
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to get all the nodes of the XML and create a list of an object. Here is my code for getting nodes.

```
public List<XMLModel2> ProcessXml()
    {
        XMLRepository xr = new XMLRepository(new POCEntities());
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        var a = xr.GetXmlFileById(1);
        doc.LoadXml(a.XmlFile);
        XmlNode rootNode = doc.DocumentElement;
        GetChildNodeWithId(rootNode);
        return NodeList;

    }





    public void GetChildNodeWithId(XmlNode node)
    {
        AddNode(node);
         XmlNodeList children = node.ChildNodes;
        if (children != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
            {
                GetChildNodeWithId(children[i]);
            }

        }
    }



    public void AddNode(XmlNode node)
    {
            XMLModel xml = new XMLModel();
            xml.NodeName = node.Name;
            xml.NodeValue = node.Value;
            NodeList.Add(xml);
        }
```

Now I am having problem to insert the NodeId and ParentId my required data suppose to look like this while converting an xml into a

```html
<parent>
   <child>
     <key> one </key>
     <key> two </key>
     <key> Three </key>
</child>
   <child>
     <key> one </key>
     <key> two </key>
     <key> Three </key>
</child>
</parent>
```

List of XMLModel should be like this:

> NodeName : Parent , NodeId : 1 , ParentId:0
>
> NodeName :Child , NodeId=2, ParentId:1
>
> NodeName : Key, NodeId : 3 , ParentId:2
>
> NodeName : Key, NodeId : 4 , ParentId:2
>
> NodeName : Key, NodeId : 5 , ParentId:2
>
> NodeName :Child , NodeId=6, ParentId:1
>
> NodeName : Key, NodeId : 7 , ParentId:6
>
> NodeName : Key, NodeId : 8 , ParentId:6
>
> NodeName : Key, NodeId : 9 , ParentId:6

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview)

```
var xml = 
    XElement.Parse(@"<parent>
    <child>
        <key> one </key>
        <key> two </key>
        <key> Three </key>
    </child>
    <child>
        <key> one </key>
        <key> two </key>
        <key> Three </key>
    </child>
    </parent>");

var elementsAndIndex =
    xml
    .DescendantsAndSelf()
    .Select((node, index) => new { index = index + 1, node })
    .ToList();

List<XmlModel> elementsWithIndexAndParentIndex =
    elementsAndIndex
    .Select(
        elementAndIndex =>
            new
            {
                Element = elementAndIndex.node,
                Index = elementAndIndex.index,
                ParentElement = elementsAndIndex.SingleOrDefault(parent => parent.node == elementAndIndex.node.Parent)
            })
    .Select(
        elementAndIndexAndParent =>
            new XmlModel
            {
                NodeName = elementAndIndexAndParent.Element.Name.LocalName,
                NodeId = elementAndIndexAndParent.Index,
                ParentId = elementAndIndexAndParent.ParentElement == null ? 0 : elementAndIndexAndParent.ParentElement.index
            })
    .ToList();
```

That should give you these results:[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked. you saved my life today. Can I know if there is any resource that I can go through to understand how it worked. I know you used LINQ but I wanted to understand it so that I can implement it future as well.

Comment: Hey Sujan, There isn't really any documentation. I guess most of the code is simple-ish, but there are two special things in there. 1) Use of the Select overload that gives you the index, as well as the item. 2). Knowing that you can match XElements by their reference as long as it originates from the same XElement instance (I used this when finding the matching parent XElement). I guess I picked this up from experience and experiments!

Answer (score 0):

You are manually deserializing the XML content by iteration. Use [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for automatic property mapping.

Also if you want a manual deserialization then use [XDocument and XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview) instead of XmlDocument class. This is easier, faster and has a modern API. The XmlDocument is from .NET 1.1 and is outdated.